# Combination of fields_for block and non fields_for block in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a form with combination of fields_for block and non fields_for block:

But the outputs are repeating, and looks like they're looping...

Maybe because, there is a fields_for block and the other one is not a fields_for / form.

How can I combine the two of them inside my `<tbody>` or `<tr>` tag.

```
<% @annual_procurement_plan.project_procurement_management_plans.each do |ppmp| %>
    <% ppmp.items.each do |itemx| %>
    <tbody>

       <%= f.fields_for :project_procurement_management_plans do |p| %>
          <%= p.fields_for :items do |item| %>
                <tr class="nested-fields info">
                <td>

              <%= item.select :category_id, Category.all.map{|c| [c.code, c.id]}%>  
             </td>
                              

             <td>
                       <%= content_tag :span, itemx.description%>
                     </td>      

             <td><%= p.text_field :pmo_end_user%>
                     </td>

        </tr>
       <% end %>
        <% end %>
     </tbody>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Any workarounds will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: can you please elaborate more? May be you can list whole form and models as well.

Comment: An outline of your model heirarchy would help, as well as exactly what the problem is. What do you mean by "looping"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the iteration item in your `fields_for` like this

```
f.fields_for :project_procurement_management_plans, ppmp do |p|
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking a guess that your model heirarchy is `annual_procurement_plan` has many `project_management_procurement_plans`, and `project_management_procurement_plan` has many `items`, the general structure of the form should be something like this:

```
<% @annual_procurement_plan.project_management_procurement_plans.each do |ppmp| %>
  <%= f.fields_for(:project_management_procurement_plans, ppmp) do |ppmp_f| %>
    # any fields for the ppmp

    <% ppmp.line_items.each do |item| %>
      <%= ppmp_f.fields_for(:line_items, item) do |item_f| %>
        # any fields for the line_item, eg
        <%= item_f.select :category_id, Category.all.map{ |c| [c.code, c.id] } %>

      <% end %>
    <% end %>

  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

In each case, you loop through each object in the association, and for each of those objects, you call `fields_for` (using the association as the first argument, and the actual object as the second). So you loop through the `ppmp`s, calling `fields_for` for each of them, and then inside each `ppmp`, you loop through all it's `line_items`, calling `fields_for` for each of them.

Make sure when you add the fields in that you use the correct form builder (ie. `item_f` for `line_item` fields, and `pmpp_f` for `pmpp` fields).